# When passed an id, my view displays a strange result

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf, mamp

So i want to click a link from a list on my index.html page, passing an id to the controller, which is received by a view, displaying the single database entry. However this only displays this;

project.whatscookin.models.data.forms.Recipe@2ff936c5
project.whatscookin.models.data.forms.Recipe@2ff936c5
*the numbers after Recipe@ change each refresh.

Controller;

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/food/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewRecipe(Model model, @PathVariable int id){
    model.addAttribute("recipeText", recipeDao.findOne(id));
    model.addAttribute("name", recipeDao.findOne(id));
    return "Recipes/food";

}
```

Index.html;

```
<table class="table">

<tr>
    <th>Name</th>

</tr>

<tr th:each="recipe : ${recipes}">
    <td th:text="${recipe.Name}"></td>
    <td th:text="${recipe.id}"></td>
    <td>
            <span th:each="recipe,iterStat : ${recipes}">

            </span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a th:href="@{/food/{id}(id=${recipe.id})}">view</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And the view, food.html;

```
<table class="table">

<tr>
    <th>Name</th>

</tr>

<h4 th:text="${name}"></h4>
<span th:text="${recipeText}"></span>
```

EDIT
Recipe Class;

```
@Entity
```

public class Recipe {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

@NotNull
@Size(min=3, max=15)
private String name;

@NotNull
@Size(min=1, message = "Recipe text must not be empty")
private String recipeText;

public Recipe() {

}

public Recipe(String name, String recipeText) {
    this.name = name;
    this.recipeText = recipeText;

}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getRecipeText() {
    return recipeText;
}

public void setRecipeText(String recipeText) {
    this.recipeText = recipeText;
}
```

}

Comment: Where do you override `toString()` in your `Recipe` class?

Comment: i don't. where would i apply that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try building your `href` using the following structure. This should give you the desired url.

```
<a th:href="@{'/food/' + ${recipe.id}}">view</a>
```

**Update**

Ok, I believe I found your problem. Please, make the following changes.

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/food/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewRecipe(Model model, @PathVariable int id){
    model.addAttribute("recipe", recipeDao.findOne(id));
    return "Recipes/food";
}
```

**food.html**

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
</tr>
<h4 th:text="${recipe.name}"></h4>
<span th:text="${recipe.recipeText}"></span>
```

The thing is that in your last approach, you weren't displaying the object's attributes, but it's signature. So, when you used `${name}`, you were actually sending referencing the object and not it's field.

Comment: same result as above. url displayed is correct, just returns this: project.whatscookin.models.data.forms.Recipe@2ff936c5 on the page

Comment: What is the type of your id? It looks like you are actually sending an object, instead of a primitive. Could you update your question with your `Recipe` class, please.

Comment: added the Recipe class above

Comment: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "recipe.name" (Recipes/food:20)

Comment: Weird, it should work. `recipeDao.findOne(id)` does return a Recipe object right? Also, when sending the recipe to your view using `model.addAttribute("recipe", recipeDao.findOne(id));`, you did use `recipe` as it's name? Another thing, make sure the object your are sending is not null.

Comment: Oh i hadn't changed the controller! your solution worked! thank you so much

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the default implementation for `toString()`.  If you want something else, you should override this method in your `Recipe` class.